# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var email_default = "Enter your email address...";
    $("input[type="email"]").attr("value", email_default);
});
```

Javascript console comes up with this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

HTML looks like this

```
<p>Name: <br><input type="text"/></p>
<p>Email: <br><input type="email" size="30" /></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the syntax highlighting, you need to either escape the quotes in the attribute selector or alternate them. Try this:

```
$('input[type="email"]').attr("value", email_default);
```